# Should redis key be unique across different datatypes?

Tags: node.js, redis, set, hashset

I am new to Redis. I am having a redis set and hset. Can I use same key for set and hset? Documents say key should be unique. Is it necessary to be unique per datatype or unique per server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - it is necessary that key names be unique as each key can store one and only one basic data structure - String, Hash, List, Set or a Sorted Set (the underlying type of Bitmaps and HLLs is a String).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I was under assumption that for each datatype there is separate key management. Issuing KEYS command listed keys from all datatypes. Now it is clear that Key should be unique in a server.